# Cannot access server shares over VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, rras, network-share

I've set up a single hosted server to use as a development environment for a web-based application.  The web app is served up fine on port `80`, however I'm struggling to get my VPN to behave how I'd expect so the developers don't have the access they require.

The VPN connects fine and I can access the back-end database (SQL Server) which resides on the server with the client tools from the laptops.  However they cannot access any shared folders.

The server's local IP address is `10.x.x.x`, and I've assigned a static IP address pool to RRAS (of `192.168.100.1 - 20`).  The clients pick up a valid IP Address (i.e. `192.168.100.9`) when they connect.

There is no name resolution setup, DNS or WINS.  When connected via VPN the clients can ping the server (`192.168.100.1`) by IP Address, but cannot map a drive to a shared folder (`net use * \\\192.168.100.1\xxxxx`) - I get

```
System error 53 has occurred.  The network path was not found.
```

I don't understand why I can ping by the ip, but not map by it.

Some details:

- Server OS is Windows 2008 (Datacenter)
- VPN is SSTP using RRAS
- Clients are all Windows 7
- I've tried temporarily disabling the firewalls

So, why can we not access the file system when everything else (ping, RDP, SQL Server clients tools) works?

Edit: Even if you don't know the answer, just a simple "yes, if it's configured correctly this should work" would be helpful.

Comment: how did you do this please as im having the same problem??

Comment: @ehughes - if you want to see how someone fixed their problem, try and find the answer that has the tick checkmark against it. On this question it's here: http://serverfault.com/questions/147117/cannot-access-server-shares-over-vpn/148595#148595

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "added a client-side static route to pass any traffic for the server's "local" ip address via the address it got from the RRAS static pool"? Did you have to do that in every client or only on the RRAS server itself? I'm having the same issue and had been spending days trying to resolve it. If you can let me know the exact steps that would be great. Thanks

Comment: I didn't need to add the static addresses to the clients, just the server I believe.  This was almost a year ago now so I'm afraid I can't recall the exact steps I took.

Comment: you mean there is something that's not automatically created by RRAS and you had to manually add something in? I'm really interested to find out as I still don't have a clue. If you can think of anything, any hint at all, I'd like to try...

Comment: If you can think of anything, email me at sanmarca@gmail.com.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was down to the MS File and Printer sharing not binding to the IP Address assigned to the server from the RRAS static pool.  As soon as I added a client-side static route to pass any traffic for the server's "local" ip address via the address it got from the RRAS static pool then everything started working.